# How to query Regular Expression in an Array of object and slice the result in Mongodb?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have documents like this..

```
"auction_list": [
    {
        "auction_id": 11368494,
        "domain": "51love.cn",
        "utf_name": "51love.cn",
        "is_idn": false,
        "auction_type": "backorder",
        "currency": "USD",
        "current_bid_price": "36.00",
        "bids": 25,
        "bidders": 4,
        "time_left": "4 days, 5 hours",
        "start_time": "2021/06/15 14:30 PST",
        "start_time_stamp": 1623792604841,
        "end_time": "2021/06/22 03:02 PST",
        "end_time_stamp": 1624356147000,
        "estibot_appraisal": "$0.00"
    },
    {
        "auction_id": 11381539,
        "domain": "meiguihualove.cn",
        "utf_name": "meiguihua.cn",
        "is_idn": false,
        "auction_type": "backorder",
        "currency": "USD",
        "current_bid_price": "15.99",
        "bids": 5,
        "bidders": 4,
        "time_left": "5 days, 5 hours",
        "start_time": "2021/06/16 14:30 PST",
        "start_time_stamp": 1623879010264,
        "end_time": "2021/06/23 03:02 PST",
        "end_time_stamp": 1624442573000,
        "estibot_appraisal": "$0.00"
    },
    {
        "auction_id": 11273186,
        "domain": "surpass.cn",
        "utf_name": "surpass.cn",
        "is_idn": false,
        "auction_type": "backorder",
        "currency": "USD",
        "current_bid_price": "14.99",
        "bids": 4,
        "bidders": 4,
        "time_left": "1 day, 5 hours",
        "start_time": "2021/06/09 14:30 PST",
        "start_time_stamp": 1623274205156,
        "end_time": "2021/06/19 03:02 PST",
        "end_time_stamp": 1624096958000,
        "estibot_appraisal": "$40.00"
    }
```

I have total 30000 objects in that array.
I want to search for the domain if the domain word contain **love** (with regex). and want to slice the result first 1 to 50th item and them 50th to 100 if found?

I tried
`ExpiredDomains.find({auction_list:{$elemMatch:{domain:'/love/'}}})`
and
`ExpiredDomains.find({auction_list:{$elemMatch:{domain:{$regex: 'love'}}})`

but this return nothing.
how can I do that? I am using Node js.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below aggregation can filter all the records with a regex.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "auction_list": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$auction_list",
          "as": "list",
          cond: {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$$list.domain",
              "regex": /love/
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$auction_list"
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 50
  }
])
```

Edit: For limiting and skipping.

Assing two different variable:

```
const a = 0;
const b = 50;

//And use it like
  {
    "$skip": a
  },
  {
    "$limit": b
  }
```

And dynamically change them. Skip will ignore first `x` record. If you'd give `skip = 50` `limit = 100` You'll get second 50 record.

Comment: Awesome, works like magic. But still uncleared how this is works as I am new to mongodb. The documentations is not clear nor beginner friendly.

Comment: Now how can I slice the results like I said the results is about a few thousands. and I want to show 50 list at a time. how to slice the results further? Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it. Oh yes ofcourse, I'm updating my answer